# macOS Preview alternative for annotating pdf files (other than Acrobat)

Tags: pdf, macos

I really like the Preview.app of macOS. However, when it comes to annotating documents, its functionality is rather limited. Of course Adobe Acrobat is the obvious alternative, however, I try to avoid products from that company. The following functions would be nice:

- runs on macOS
- highlighting
- replace (strikethrough) text
- add text
- add annotation boxes

Answer (score 1):

As a free (but obviously limited) option, John already mentioned [Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/) which is a nice application. But you can also have a look at [Foxit Reader](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/foxit-reader-leading-pdf-reader-by-foxit/id1032155965?mt=12) which I think also does what you need it for.

But since you weren't looking directly at free, and the reason against Acrobat was not about money, you may want to try [PDFPen](https://smilesoftware.com/pdfpen) which is a more powerful (than the aforementioned free solutions, and more similar to Acrobat) PDF Editor. It costs $75 but has a free trial.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free pdf reader called Skim. I think it does all the things you listed but I can't guarantee that. It is free though so worth a try.